# Rails Admin - removing a related object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-admin

I'm using [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) on one of my sites. It's great so far, but I can't figure out how to remove a related object from an edit page.

Example:
I have two models Property and PropertyImage.

```
class Property
  has_many :property_images, :dependent => :destroy
end

class PropertyImage
  belongs_to :property
end
```

I can go to the edit screen for an instance of either model, and I can delete PropertyImages from their list view. But when I edit a Property, I want to be able to delete a PropertyImage that's associated with it. Is there a way to turn on this functionality in rails_admin?

Here's what I can see.

[image: rails_admin interface]

Note: the "Delete Image" button isn't what I'm looking for - it's just because there's an upload association to the Image field. It only edits the PropertyImage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same question, and found an answer that works for me after reading your question.

In order to properly setup up the editing of PropertyImage from the Property form, you probably want to specify that it can work with the nested form:

```
# property.rb
class Property
  has_many :property_images, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :property_images, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Including the `:allow_destroy` option should make the delete option show up for the nested item.

[image: Screenshot of nested form with delete button]

Comment: Making changes to your model are usually reflected in rails admin without a server restart, but I had to restart mine for this change to take effect.

Comment: Should be  accepts_nested_attributes_for **:property_images**, :allow_destroy => true

Comment: I had nearly exactly the same issue as the question, and while this answer provided the delete button in the top left corner as pictured, the "Delete Image" button, as pictured in the question, remained.  In order to circumvent this, I had to override the partial: basically I took [the original form upload partial](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_file_upload.html.haml), deleted [the code for the button](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_file_upload.html.haml#L9), and that solved my issue.