# Rails_admin: How to delete nested objects in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I am having:

```
class Entity < AR::Base
  has_many :representatives, 
    inverse_of: :entity, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :representatives, 
    allow_destroy: true
end
```

and the Entity's rails admin form allows me to create nested representatives inline. Though, I am unable to remove representatives through the entity's nested form after they are already saved. I am suspicious that this is related with rails 4 since there are other similar questions with answers that do not work:

[Rails Admin - removing a related object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679309/rails-admin-removing-a-related-object)

Comment: Did you tried to destroy an object from the rails console? And dependent objects are destroyed from there?

Comment: yes I did. It works and it wasn't useful.

Comment: I know it's not useful, but helps to track down the problem. So, if dependent objects are destroyed then it's not a Rails 4 issue but a RailsAdmin issue. I think RailsAdmin calls #delete instead of #destroy  because #destroy is the only way to get dependent objects destroyed, #delete does not call handlers.