# Rails Admin unable to delete related object on rails 4.1.9

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I'm trying to delete a related object on rails_admin

On `Rails 4.1.9`, the image upload is being handled by carrierwave.

My models:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

And:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Here's a screen grap:

[image: rails_admin delete image]

When I hit the delete button, the image disappears (jQuery), nothing happens on the terminal, when I refresh the page, the image shows up again.

On the console both `.destroy` and `.delete` works to remove the asset.

I've went through related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679309/rails-admin-removing-a-related-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727474/rails-admin-how-to-delete-nested-objects-in-rails-4)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Solution:

Switch to Active Admin.